# JQuery hover() possibilities?

Tags: jquery, arrays, function, hover

I'm using hover() as suggested in the documentation:

```
 $("#div").hover(
     function(){$(this).addClass('cie_hover');},          
     function(){$(this).removeClass('cie_hover') ;}      
 );
```

Is there a way I can use more functions on other objects? And if so what would be the syntax to introduce functions in array?

What I would like to do with that is change the class of the div I'm hovering and `sildeDown()` another one elsewhere with that same `hover()` action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are just function call backs.  The body of the function can be anything you want:

```
 $('#div').hover(
      function(){
           $(this).addClass('cie_hover');
           $('#otherdiv').slideDown();
      }, function(){
           $(this).removeClass('cie_hover');
           $('#otherdiv').slideUp();
      }
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add it into the anonymous function executed on hover over

```
 $("#div").hover(
 function(){
     $(this).addClass('cie_hover');
     $('selector for thing you want to slide down').slideDown();
 },          
 function(){
     $(this).removeClass('cie_hover');
 });
```